# Hidden form field value not correct when passing data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have a PHP form working with MySQL and passing data to another page, In the first page, a mysql query selects some records and then prints it on the page, one of this records is obviously the ID, which is also printed in the value of an hidden field, in order to use it in the next page

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
```

and the result is correct, I have 10 different ids when checking the page output code

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="3" />
...
```

the problem comes when I submit the form (I have 1 form for each DB result, so if I have 10 entries I have also 10 hidden fields with 10 different values), even if I submit the **2nd** or the **10th** form, in the next page, the value of $_POST['cat_id'] is always 1, according to a general print of $_POST

```
Array
(

[cat_id] => 1

)
```

Does someone understands why?

**EDIT**: Adding the complete forms output script for clarification

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

  <?php
    if($c == 0){
  ?>
      <h3>Il catalogo è momentaneamente vuoto.</h3>
  <?php
    } else {

      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption-img" style="background: url('imgs/thumb.jpg');"></div>
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <div class="caption-link">
            <h3><?php echo $row['titolo']; ?></h3>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span>
          </div>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Password</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Perfavore inserisci la password necessaria per visualizzare questo elemento</p>
        <form action="show.php" method="post">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="psw" />
          <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="view">Prosegui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    

        <?php
      }

    }
  ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have multiple forms on page, you should have multiple `<form>input fields here, submit here</form>` .. if you only have 1 `<form>` then all your inputs fields will be submitted

Comment: In his Question he says he has 1 form for each entry, so 10 forms

Comment: @Ciccio - i understand he does, however if he was opening and closing the forms correctly, he probably wouldn't have this issue.. I suppose another issue could be nested forms

Comment: Are you submitting the forms with some JS validation? could it be possible your JS validation is submitting the first form instead of the intended form?

Comment: Yeah I think we could help easier if we saw the complete code here.

Comment: Added the complete code

Comment: @K3nzie you have an issue with the way your div's close and open.. see my answer

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ didn't work

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ Yeah I did change also the opening position

Comment: Also I tried with the get method, and it's the same, the id is always one, I've checked files hundred times, really strange

Comment: Can you change the name to cat_id[] and tell me if it prints all the ID's

Comment: I didn't think about that, it's probably the good way, anyway I solved it, simply not using all that forms in one page, I added one more step, but at least it works well, thanks for all the help guys, the question can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Your form is broken, it cannot have its parent element closing before the form closes:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <p>Perfavore inserisci la password necessaria per visualizzare questo elemento</p>
        <form action="show.php" method="post">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="psw" />
          <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
      </div> <!-- HERE IS YOUR ISSUE -->
      <div class="modal-footer"> <!-- HERE IS YOUR ISSUE -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="view">Prosegui</button>
        </form>
      </div>
```

It should look more like this:

```
<form action="show.php" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Perfavore inserisci la password necessaria per visualizzare questo elemento</p>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="psw" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="view">Prosegui</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @K3nzie did you also change the position of the form opening?